# Delphi - How to read the entire Excel Sheet to a ClientDataSet?

Tags: delphi, variant

I'm having an issue reading data from an Excel sheet into OleVariant objects. My procedure reads the lines of the sheet correctly, but it only reads until the line 3162, but my sheet has 3272 lines. Does it have any limit of size for the Excel file?
The code is below:

```
procedure TfrmEnvioDeEstoque.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Excel, Book, Sheet, Range: OleVariant;
  Data: Variant;
  i: Integer;
  j: Integer;
const
  xlDown = -4121;
begin
  inherited;
  opnSheet.Execute();

  Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  try
    Book := Excel.WorkBooks.Open(opnSheet.FileName);
    Sheet := Book.Worksheets.Item['Sheet1'];

    Range := Sheet.Range['A2', Sheet.Range['O2'].End[xlDown]];
    Data := Range.Value;

    cdsProducts.DisableControls;
    cdsProducts.EmptyDataSet;
    cdsProducts.First;

    for i := 1 to VarArrayHighBound(Data, 1) do
    begin
      cdsProducts.Append;
      cdsProductsmarcar.AsString       := 'T';
      cdsProductsreferencia.AsString   := Data[i, 1];
      cdsProductsnome.AsString         := Data[i, 2];
      cdsProductssku.AsString          := Data[i, 3];
      cdsProductsatt1.AsString         := Data[i, 4];
      cdsProductsatt2.AsString         := Data[i, 5];
      cdsProductsatt3.AsString         := Data[i, 6];
      cdsProductsquantidade.AsInteger  := StrToInt(Data[i, 7]);
      cdsProductspreco.AsFloat         := StrToFloat(Data[i, 8]);
      cdsProductsvariante.AsString     := Data[i, 9];
      cdsProductspeso.AsString         := Data[i, 10];
      cdsProductslargura.AsString      := Data[i, 11];
      cdsProductscomprimento.AsString  := Data[i, 12];
      cdsProductsaltura.AsString       := Data[i, 13];
      cdsProductstags.AsString         := Data[i, 14];
      cdsProductscodigoBarras.AsString := Data[i, 15];
    end;

  finally
    Range := Unassigned;
    Sheet := Unassigned;
    Book := Unassigned;
    Excel.Quit;
    Excel := Unassigned;

    cdsProducts.First;
    cdsProducts.EnableControls;
  end;

end;
```

The sheet has the columns from A to O, that's why I set a range for the Data. That way, I can set my ClientDataSet fields the way I do above. If there's an easier way to do it, I would like to know. Thank you!

Comment: I have used code which is very similar indeed to yours to import data from quite a large spreadsheet, but did not run into any limitations regarding the number of rows in the worksheet.  I would suggest that you temporarily replace your range-setting code with hard-coded values for the starting and ending row numbers.  I would expect that to work correctly, so your problem may simply be that `Sheet.Range['O2'].End[xlDown]` does not take you to the end row of the data.

Comment: The End method only looks for non-blank cells, so if some cell in column O is blank, End will not go past it. There is no single, beautiful method to find the true "last" cell, but here are some tips: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/

Comment: Matthias B, you were right! There are some empty cells after O3162. I have never thought about looking for that. Thank you all for your help, the problem is solved.